# Duplicate Case Item: "0"

Tags: .net, delphi-prism

Could someone please tell me what is exactly wrong with the way my case statement is written. I can't see anything wrong with it, but the compiler keeps raising the following error, "Duplicate case item: '0'," for the line with HatchSytle.Horizontal. If I comment out that line it is fine and compiles without any error.

As you can see, none of the elements I am checking on are the same. So, I shouldn't get any error. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
    case TMakerGraphic(obj).theBrushStyle of
    HatchStyle.Min: BrushStyleCombo.SelectedIndex := 1;
    HatchStyle.ZigZag: BrushStyleCombo.SelectedIndex := 0;
    HatchStyle.BackwardDiagonal: BrushStyleCombo.SelectedIndex := 2;
    HatchStyle.ForwardDiagonal: BrushStyleCombo.SelectedIndex := 3;
    HatchStyle.Cross: BrushStyleCombo.SelectedIndex := 4;
    HatchStyle.DiagonalCross: BrushStyleCombo.SelectedIndex := 5;
    HatchStyle.Horizontal: BrushStyleCombo.SelectedIndex := 6;  <<<< Line raising error.
    HatchStyle.Vertical: BrushStyleCombo.SelectedIndex := 7;
    end;
```

Thanks

Comment: This reminds me how cool it is in Pascal not to have to add a break statement for each case...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchstyle.aspx

Check the docs for horizontal and min.  they refer to the same enumeration item.

Answer (score 4):

Min and horizontal are associated to the same int value:

```
    public enum HatchStyle
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies hatch style System.Drawing.Drawing2D.HatchStyle.Horizontal.
        Min = 0,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A pattern of horizontal lines.
        Horizontal = 0,
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Only thing I can think of would be that the enum `HatchStyle` has zero defined twice, once at `Horizontal`, and once somewhere else.

Is `HatchStyle` your code, or is it a third-party library you're using? Either way, I'd start by looking at (or disassembling) that code to see what the numeric values for the enum are.

Comment: Just saw from the other answers that `HatchStyle` is part of the framework - I guess I haven't done any drawing code in .NET in awhile...